# Mutable members should not be stored or returned directly - com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList - "false positive"

Tags: sonarqube

We return an immutable list and get the critical Sonar warning "Mutable members should not be stored or returned directly"

```
public List<A> getA() {
    return A;
}
```

A is initialized as an ImmutableList.copyOf(B) in the constructor.
Is it possible to take these immutable implementations into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make variable A of type ImmutableList and it should not raise an issue.

Comment: thanks for the fast feedback. wouldn't this approach raise an " Declarations should use Java collection interfaces such as "List" rather than specific implementation classes such as "LinkedList" squid:S1319" kind of issue?

Comment: Nope, it should be ok for private fields since version 3.4, see ticket to restrict the check to publics.
https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-808

Comment: what is the change need to be done for setter method